# Generate a hexdump of a file!

Tags: code-golf, hexadecimal

In this task, your goal is to write a program for generating hexdumps of files of arbitrary types.

## Input

The input consists of a (relative or absolute) path to the file to be processed. It may be taken from STDIN, a function argument, or a command line argument.

## Output

The output (which may be written to a separate plaintext file or to STDOUT) should contain a hexdump of the file, formatted as follows:

- A-F may be uppercase or lowercase, but should be consistent throughout the output
- Spaces between bytes on the same line
- 16 bytes per line (the last line may be shorter, depending on the input file)
- A trailing newline at the end of the output is permissible
- A single trailing space at the beginning or end of each line is permissible, but should be consistent throughout the output.

## Some test cases:

**Input text file:**

```
Hello, World!
```

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21
```

**Input text file:**

```
"Look behind you! It's a three-headed monkey!"
```

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

```
22 4C 6F 6F 6B 20 62 65 68 69 6E 64 20 79 6F 75
21 20 49 74 27 73 20 61 20 74 68 72 65 65 2D 68
65 61 64 65 64 20 6D 6F 6E 6B 65 79 21 22
```

**Input JVM class file:**

https://googledrive.com/host/0B66Q2_YrkhNnQkYzY0hyck04NWc/HelloWorld.class

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

```
CA FE BA BE 00 00 00 34 00 1D 0A 00 06 00 0F 09
00 10 00 11 08 00 12 0A 00 13 00 14 07 00 15 07
00 16 01 00 06 3C 69 6E 69 74 3E 01 00 03 28 29
56 01 00 04 43 6F 64 65 01 00 0F 4C 69 6E 65 4E
75 6D 62 65 72 54 61 62 6C 65 01 00 04 6D 61 69
6E 01 00 16 28 5B 4C 6A 61 76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67
2F 53 74 72 69 6E 67 3B 29 56 01 00 0A 53 6F 75
72 63 65 46 69 6C 65 01 00 0F 48 65 6C 6C 6F 57
6F 72 6C 64 2E 6A 61 76 61 0C 00 07 00 08 07 00
17 0C 00 18 00 19 01 00 0D 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20
57 6F 72 6C 64 21 07 00 1A 0C 00 1B 00 1C 01 00
0A 48 65 6C 6C 6F 57 6F 72 6C 64 01 00 10 6A 61
76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67 2F 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 01 00
10 6A 61 76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67 2F 53 79 73 74 65
6D 01 00 03 6F 75 74 01 00 15 4C 6A 61 76 61 2F
69 6F 2F 50 72 69 6E 74 53 74 72 65 61 6D 3B 01
00 13 6A 61 76 61 2F 69 6F 2F 50 72 69 6E 74 53
74 72 65 61 6D 01 00 07 70 72 69 6E 74 6C 6E 01
00 15 28 4C 6A 61 76 61 2F 6C 61 6E 67 2F 53 74
72 69 6E 67 3B 29 56 00 21 00 05 00 06 00 00 00
00 00 02 00 01 00 07 00 08 00 01 00 09 00 00 00
1D 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 05 2A B7 00 01 B1 00 00
00 01 00 0A 00 00 00 06 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 09
00 0B 00 0C 00 01 00 09 00 00 00 25 00 02 00 01
00 00 00 09 B2 00 02 12 03 B6 00 04 B1 00 00 00
01 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 08 00
04 00 01 00 0D 00 00 00 02 00 0E
```

**Input ICO image file:**

http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/favicon.ico

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

340 lines starting with `00 00 01 00 02 00 10 10 00 00 01 00 20 00 68 04`

**Input PNG image file:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPAwA.png

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

7982 lines starting with `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52`

**Input MP3 Audio file:**

http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/download/142057

(CC BY-NC-SA NemesisTheory 2008)

**Output (STDOUT or separate text file):**

300769 lines starting with `49 44 33 03 00 00 00 00 1F 76 54 49 54 32 00 00`

Comment: Isn't this trivial using `xxd`?

Comment: It'd be easier with `hexdump`.

Comment: Yes, it says in the specs that `A-F may be uppercase or lowercase, but should be consistent throughout the output`

Answer (score 2):

## Bash/sed, 35 bytes

`xxd -p -c16 $1|sed 's/\(..\)/\1 /g'`

Basically.

Comment: Nope. `echo "Hello, World" | xxd` generates some junk, then clumps of every 2 bytes strung together, then the actual text.

Comment: The challenge says the input is a filename not a string.

Comment: Oh wait I see what you mean. Fair enough

Comment: Same applies for `xxd test.txt` given `test.txt` contains `Hello, World!`

Comment: Fixed that. Now it should output pretty